# Optimize this function (in C++)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, g++

I have a cpu-consuming code, where some function with a loop is executed *many* times. Every optimization in this loop brings noticeable performance gain. Question: How would you optimize this loop (there is not much more to optimize though...)?

```
void theloop(int64_t in[], int64_t out[], size_t N)
{
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int64_t v = in[i];
        max += v;
        if (v > max) max = v;
        out[i] = max;
    }
}
```

I tried a few things, e.g. I replaced arrays with pointers that were incremented in every loop, but (surprisingly) i *lost* some performance instead of gaining...

Edit:

- changed name of one variable (`itsMaximums`, error)
- the function is an a method of a class
- in and put are `int64_t` , so are negative and positive
- `(v > max) *can* evaluate to true: consider the situation when actual max is negative
- the code runs on 32-bit pc (development) and 64-bit (production)
- `N` is unknown at compile time
- I tried some SIMD, but I failed to increase performance... (the overhead of moving the variables to `_m128i`, executing and storing back was higher than than SSE speed gain. Yet I am not an expert on SSE, so maybe I had a poor code)

Results:

I added some loop unfolding, *and* a nice hack from Alex'es post. Below I paste some results:

1. original: 14.0s
2. unfolded loop (4 iterations): 10.44s
3. Alex'es trick: 10.89s
4. 2) and 3) at once: 11.71s

strage, that 4) is not faster than 3) and 4). Below code for 4):

```
for(size_t i = 1; i < N; i+=CHUNK) {
    int64_t t_in0 = in[i+0];
    int64_t t_in1 = in[i+1];
    int64_t t_in2 = in[i+2];
    int64_t t_in3 = in[i+3];


    max &= -max >> 63;
    max += t_in0;
    out[i+0] = max;

    max &= -max >> 63;
    max += t_in1;
    out[i+1] = max;

    max &= -max >> 63;
    max += t_in2;
    out[i+2] = max;

    max &= -max >> 63;
    max += t_in3;
    out[i+3] = max;

}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  Is itsMaximums a global?  Are the numbers in the in array both positive and negative?

Comment: where is itsMaximums defined?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something `v > max` can never evaluate to true.

Comment: Maybe guessing too much here but, what do you need that `max += v` for? Doesn't the loop calculate the max of the numbers in `in` at every index?

Comment: @DavidGallagher if v is negative then the condition may be true. I was first wondering the same thing :)

Comment: The critical path of this loop should only be 3 instructions/iteration on any competent compiler: `add + cmp + cmov` (roughly 4 cycles on most machines). I'd say that's pretty fast already. What is the current performance?

Comment: Not performance related but why is N a size_t and i an uint32_t?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to go down to the level of assembly? With such simple code, it's likely that the compiler will overrule many of your optimization attempts.

Comment: Why would you expect to get a speedup by replacing arrays with pointers?

Comment: @jalf: I expected it because I can iterate pointers directly, instead of iterating a variable _and_ adding it to the base pointer

Comment: @Jakub: how do you think pointers are incremented? That's an addition as well. ;) But with pointers, you have one long dependency chain (you need to compute the pointer's current value before you can compute its next value). With indices, you only need to know the base address, then you can compute *any* offset from it. To be honest, I wouldn't expect it to make *any* difference in most cases (since the compiler knows they're equivalent), but where it *does* make a difference, I'd actually expect indices to be faster

Comment: @Mysticial: plus a load and a store. :) And if the compiler can't guarantee that `in` and `out` are distinct, it won't be able to reorder those much, and then *that* will definitely be on the critical path. :)

Comment: @jalf: True on the aliasing part. But assuming no aliasing, the load and store are not on the critical path. You could do the load for the next iteration and the store for the previous iteration concurrently with the current iteration. It might take a spectacular amount of unrolling to make this happen, but it's possible.

Comment: assuming no aliasing, the memory loads/stores can be reordered to speed things up a lot, I agree. I'm not sure if I'd say it's not on the critical path *at all*, but it'd certainly make a major difference

Comment: @JakubM.: get a 64-bit machine to test on. It's meaningless to perform low-level optimizations like these if you're testing on a completely different instruction set than it's going to use in production. The generated code is going to be quite different when targeting a 64-bit machine, and that's what you should try to optimize

Comment: @Jalf, if the same code runs on 32bit and 64bit systems, surely it hasn't been targeted for a 64 bit? (e.g. the bulk of applications running on Windows 7 64 bit are still 32 bit apps.  True that the performance characteristics may be different though.

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: well, if (a) the target machine is 64-bit and (b) the code contains 64-bit arithmetics, and (c) performance is considered important, then I'd expect them to make a 64-bit build. Otherwise that should be teh #1 optimization to consider

Comment: added a bit to my post in response to your edit

Comment: @JakubM, is the code native 64 bit, or 32 bit running on a 64 bit platform?  It would also help if you copied the compiler generated assembler up, as it gives better visibility to what's happening rather than trying to double guess the optimizer.

Comment: @JakubM.: Is there an index N so that for `i >= N`, `in[i] >= 0` ?

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I am afraid I don't get your question, but `N` is the of `in` and `out` size, so after `N` you have only seg fault

Comment: @JakubM.: bad choice of constant sorry... my question pertains to some additional properties of the input. Is the input random or does it have some properties that we could potentially exploit. For example, if the input was positive up to a certain point or from a certain point onto the end it we could perhaps split the work in different phases, each with its dedicated loop.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: the input is random

Comment: @sehe: thanks, this `i=1` is correct for the original algorithm, although for this example it does not make sense : )

Comment: @JakubM. are you sure it does when doing the unrolled version? It will loop while `i<N` and dereferences `in[i+3]` inside the body; this will read `in[N]` eventually, which is out of array bounds.

Comment: @sehe: `i=1` in the *original* one makes sense, believe me : ) here, rather not, it is a minor detail

Comment: @JakubM.: ... I don't get it. I never said `i=1` was wrong in the original version. If you agree that it is off-by-1 in the unrolled version, could you not just edit the question to fix it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5056/discussion-between-sehe-and-jakub-m)

Comment: @JakubM. [6502](http://stackoverflow.com/users/320726/6502) just mentioned in chat, that with CUDA there is a pattern (known as _scan_) that efficiently does an operation similar to yours. See http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples#scan - I think it might interest you if you still have the goal of optimizing this further
([more background](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>> <strike>#**Announcement** see [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5056/discussion-between-sehe-and-jakub-m)
> > _Hi Jakub, what would you say if I have found a version that uses a heuristic optimization that, for random data distributed uniformly will result in ~3.2x speed increase for `int64_t` (10.56x effective using `float`s)?_
> 
I have yet to find the time to update the post, but the explanation and code can be found through the chat. 
 
> I used the same test-bed code (below) to verify that the results are correct and exactly match the original implementation from your OP</strike></sub>
   **Edit**: ironically... that testbed had a fatal flaw, which rendered the results invalid: the heuristic version was in fact skipping parts of the input, but because existing output wasn't being cleared, it appeared to have the correct output... (still editing...)

---

Ok, I have published a benchmark based on your code versions, and also my proposed use of `partial_sum`.

***Find all the code here* https://gist.github.com/1368992#file_test.cpp**

### Features

For a default config of

```
#define MAGNITUDE     20
#define ITERATIONS    1024
#define VERIFICATION  1
#define VERBOSE       0

#define LIMITED_RANGE 0    // hide difference in output due to absense of overflows
#define USE_FLOATS    0
```

It will (*see **[output fragment](https://gist.github.com/1368992#gistcomment-63508)** here*):

- run 100 x 1024 iterations (i.e. 100 different random seeds)
- for data length 1048576 (2^20).
- The random input data is **uniformly distributed** over the full range of the element data type (`int64_t`)
- Verify output by generating a **hash digest** of the output array and comparing it to the *reference implementation* from the OP.

### Results

There are a number of (surprising or unsurprising) results:

0. there is **no significant** performance difference between any of the algorithms whatsoever (*for integer data*), provided you are compiling with optimizations enabled. (See [Makefile](https://gist.github.com/1368992#file_makefile); my arch is 64bit, Intel Core Q9550 with gcc-4.6.1)
1. The algorithms are **not equivalent** (you'll see hash sums differ): notably the bit fiddle proposed by Alex doesn't handle integer overflow in quite the same way (this can be hidden defining

   ```
   #define LIMITED_RANGE 1
   ```

   which limits the input data so overflows won't occur; Note that the `partial_sum_incorrect` version shows equivalent C++ non-bitwise _arithmetic operations that yield the same *different* results:

   ```
   return max<0 ? v :  max + v;
   ```

   Perhaps, it is ok for your purpose?)
2. **Surprisingly** It is not more expensive to calculate both definitions of the max algorithm at once. You can see this being done inside `partial_sum_correct`: it calculates both 'formulations' of max in the same loop; This is really not more than a triva here, because none of the two methods is significantly faster...
3. Even more surprisingly **a big performance boost** can be had when you are able to use `float` instead of `int64_t`. A quick and dirty hack can be applied to the benchmark

   ```
   #define USE_FLOATS    0
   ```

   showing that the STL based algorithm (`partial_sum_incorrect`) runs **aproximately 2.5x faster** when using `float` instead of `int64_t` (!!!).
   **Note:**

   - that the naming of `partial_sum_incorrect` only relates to integer overflow, which doesn't apply to floats; this can be seen from the fact that the hashes match up, so in fact it is *partial_sum_float_correct* :)
   - that the current implementation of `partial_sum_correct` is doing double work that causes it to perform badly in floating point mode. See bullet **3.**
4. (And there was that off-by-1 bug in the loop-unrolled version from the OP I mentioned before)

### Partial sum

For your interest, the partial sum application looks like this in C++11:

```
std::partial_sum(data.begin(), data.end(), output.begin(), 
        [](int64_t max, int64_t v) -> int64_t
        { 
            max += v;
            if (v > max) max = v;
            return max;
        });
```

Comment: the algorithm does *not* calculate sums and max(sums). the condition `if (v > max) max = v` *is* important, it is a part of a larger  algorithm.

Comment: Great answer! I noticed that using the single-line form of the function (2) is not *really* correct. Although, I  noticed that using it increased the performance by ~40% (and I still got proper results)

Comment: Wow, congratulations on going the extra mile and actually implementing things! Regarding `int64_t` vs `float`, it might be a cache effect: `float` is only 32 bits wide (`double` is 64 bits wide).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: yeah that's what I suspect. I'll probably update my post only tonight (wait wait better yet, let me just hold onto that until a bonus appears - wink wink :)). I'd love to get some real life test data first, actually. The heuristic can certainly be improved, this was just my first stab at one.

Comment: Since overflow of signed numbers results in undefined behavior your second point is only circumstantial. As soon as the result overflows all bets are off.

Comment: @Voo: thx for that, I kind of forgot. That makes things even better, unless of course, the OP wants backwards compatibility with his undefined-overflow behaviours :)

Comment: @MatthieuM. I suppose that the `float` boost might be caused also by SSE optimizations

Comment: @JakubM.: I don't know SSE well, but I am not sure that your use case fits well with SSE, the computation is quite uncommon.

Answer (score 15):

First, you need to look at the generated assembly. Otherwise you have no way of knowing what actually *happens* when this loop is executed.

Now: is this code running on a 64-bit machine? If not, those 64-bit additions might hurt a bit.

This loop seems an obvious candidate for using SIMD instructions. SSE2 supports a number of SIMD instructions for integer arithmetics, *including* some that work on two 64-bit values.

Other than that, see if the compiler properly unrolls the loop, and if not, do so yourself. Unroll a couple of iterations of the loop, and then reorder the hell out of it. Put all the memory loads at the top of the loop, so they can be started as early as possible.

For the `if` line, check that the compiler is generating a conditional move, rather than a branch.

Finally, see if your compiler supports something like the `restrict`/`__restrict` keyword. It's not standard in C++, but it is *very* useful for indicating to the compiler that `in` and `out` do not point to the same addresses.

Is the size (`N`) known at compile-time? If so, make it a template parameter (and then try passing `in` and `out` as references to properly-sized arrays, as this may also help the compiler with aliasing analysis)

Just some thoughts off the top of my head. But again, study the disassembly. You need to know what the compiler does for you, and especially, what it *doesn't* do for you.

**Edit**

with your edit:

```
max &= -max >> 63;
max += t_in0;
out[i+0] = max;
```

what strikes me is that you added a *huge* dependency chain.
Before the result can be computed, max must be negated, the result must be shifted, the result of *that* must be *and*'ed together with its original value, and the result of **that** must be added to another variable.

In other words, all these operations have to be serialized. You can't start one of them before the previous has finished. That's not necessarily a speedup. Modern pipelined out-of-order CPUs like to execute lots of things in parallel. Tying it up with a single long chain of dependant instructions is one of the most crippling things you can do. (Of course, it if can be interleaved with other iterations, it might work out better. But my gut feeling is that a simple conditional move instruction would be preferable)

Comment: +1 for studying the generated code. Doing optimizations at this small scale without knowing what optimizations the compiler is doing behind your back is like driving blind.

Comment: unrolling gave some improvement, from 2.0 sec to 1.8 sec (unrolled 10 iterations)

Comment: IME, unrolling is only the first step. Once you've unrolled the code, that gives you much more room to reorder the code. So play around and see how much further you can push it

Comment: @jalf: after unrolling, do I have much "field of maneuver" here? What I can do is to load it at the beginning, but I cannot reorder too much those three lines starting from `max += v`, because each iteration here depends on the previous one

Comment: no, you're right, that limits your options quite a bit. But even so, play around, experiment. Sometimes, fiddling with the code can give pretty surprising results. Something that looks wasteful (say, recomputing expressions several times, or doing multiple computations based on estimated data, and then at the end selecting the correct one) might actually turn out faster, if it breaks up dependency chains and gives the CPU more breathing room

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes, you need to step backward and look over it again. The first question is obviously, do you need this ? Could there be an alternative algorithm that would perform better ?

That being said, and supposing for the sake of this question that you already settled on this algorithm, we can try and reason about what we actually have.

*Disclaimer: the method I am describing is inspired by the successful method Tim Peters used to improve the traditional introsort implementation, leading to [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). So please bear with me ;)*

**1. Extracting Properties**

The main issue I can see is the dependency between iterations, which will prevent much of the possible optimizations and thwart many attempts at parallelizing.

```
int64_t v = in[i];
max += v;
if (v > max) max = v;
out[i] = max;
```

Let us rework this code in a functional fashion:

```
max = calc(in[i], max);
out[i] = max;
```

Where:

```
int64_t calc(int64_t const in, int64_t const max) {
  int64_t const bumped = max + in;
  return in > bumped ? in : bumped;
}
```

Or rather, a simplified version (baring overflow since it's undefined):

```
int64_t calc(int64_t const in, int64_t const max) {
  return 0 > max ? in : max + in;
}
```

Do you notice the tip point ? The behavior changes depending on whether the ill-named(*) `max` is positive or negative.

This tipping point makes it interesting to watch the values in `in` more closely, especially according to the effect they might have on `max`:

- `max < 0` and `in[i] < 0` then `out[i] = in[i] < 0`
- `max < 0` and `in[i] > 0` then `out[i] = in[i] > 0`
- `max > 0` and `in[i] < 0` then `out[i] = (max + in[i]) ?? 0`
- `max > 0` and `in[i] > 0` then `out[i] = (max + in[i]) > 0`

(*) ill-named because it is also an accumulator, which the name hides. I have no better suggestion though.

**2. Optimizing operations**

This leads us to discover interesting cases:

- if we have a slice `[i, j)` of the array containing only negative values (which we call negative slice), then we could do a `std::copy(in + i, in + j, out + i)` and `max = out[j-1]`
- if we have a slice `[i, j)` of the array containing only positive values, then it's a pure accumulation code (which can easily be unrolled)
- `max` gets positive as soon as `in[i]` is positive

Therefore, it could be interesting (but maybe not, I make no promise) to establish a profile of the input before actually working with it. Note that the profile could be made chunk by chunk for large inputs, for example tuning the chunk size based on the cache line size.

For references, the 3 routines:

```
void copy(int64_t const in[], int64_t out[],
          size_t const begin, size_t const end)
{
  std::copy(in + begin, in + end, out + begin);
} // copy

void accumulate(int64_t const in[], int64_t out[],
                size_t const begin, size_t const end)
{
  assert(begin != 0);

  int64_t max = out[begin-1];

  for (size_t i = begin; i != end; ++i) {
    max += in[i];
    out[i] = max;
  }
} // accumulate

void regular(int64_t const in[], int64_t out[],
             size_t const begin, size_t const end)
{
  assert(begin != 0);

  int64_t max = out[begin - 1];

  for (size_t i = begin; i != end; ++i)
  {
    max = 0 > max ? in[i] : max + in[i];
    out[i] = max;
  }
}
```

Now, supposing that we can somehow characterize the input using a simple structure:

```
struct Slice {
  enum class Type { Negative, Neutral, Positive };
  Type type;
  size_t begin;
  size_t end;
};

typedef void (*Func)(int64_t const[], int64_t[], size_t, size_t);

Func select(Type t) {
  switch(t) {
  case Type::Negative: return &copy;
  case Type::Neutral: return &regular;
  case Type::Positive: return &accumulate;
  }
}

void theLoop(std::vector<Slice> const& slices, int64_t const in[], int64_t out[]) {
  for (Slice const& slice: slices) {
    Func const f = select(slice.type);
    (*f)(in, out, slice.begin, slice.end);
  }
}
```

Now, unless introsort the work in the loop is minimal, so computing the characteristics might be too costly as is... however it leads itself well to **parallelization**.

**3. Simple parallelization**

Note that the characterization is a pure function of the input. Therefore, supposing that you work in a chunk per chunk fashion, it could be possible to have, in parallel:

- Slice Producer: a characterizer thread, which computes the `Slice::Type` value
- Slice Consumer: a worker thread, which actually executes the code

Even if the input is essentially random, providing the chunk is small enough (for example, a CPU L1 cache line) there might be chunks for which it does work. Synchronization between the two threads can be done with a simple thread-safe queue of `Slice` (producer/consumer) and adding a `bool last` attribute to stop consumption or by creating the `Slice` in a vector with a `Unknown` type, and having the consumer block until it's known (using atomics).

Note: because characterization is pure, it's embarrassingly parallel.

**4. More Parallelization: Speculative work**

Remember this innocent remark: *`max` gets positive as soon as `in[i]` is positive*.

Suppose that we can guess (reliably) that the `Slice[j-1]` will produce a `max` value that is negative, then the computation on `Slice[j]` are independent of what preceded them, and we can start the work right now!

Of course, it's a guess, so we might be wrong... but once we have fully characterized all the Slices, we have idle cores, so we might as well use them for speculative work! And if we're wrong ? Well, the Consumer thread will simply gently erase our mistake and replace it with the correct value.

The heuristic to speculatively compute a `Slice` should be simple, and it will have to be tuned. It may be adaptative as well... but that may be more difficult!

**Conclusion**

Analyze your dataset and try to find if it's possible to break dependencies. If it is you can probably take advantage of it, even without going multi-thread.

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately a bit too much hinges on slicing / source profile. Still I really like the way you worded what I have been pondering myself. I'm not sure I could have done such good job - clearly not in the same timespan.

Comment: @Matthieu: I like the analysis! Precious hints, even for further algorithms

Comment: Just using `calc` in this short, single line form, reduced execution times by ~40%

Comment: @JakubM.: out of curiosity, what compiler and options are you using? My benchmark compares those options and they come out as perfectly equivalent in performance (see benchmarks). Using `calc` should, IMO, not make any difference on an optimizing compiler (it _does_ clarify the code, though)

Comment: @JakubM.: I am surprised that it did have an influence! I only rewrote it for clarity. I would have thought the branchless version faster... but then it's hard to predict what optimizers do :)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I've implemented one heuristic that "I had been pondering" myself. It looks promising, allthough, as an heuristic, it does depend on the actual input data. Until now, I'm seeing between 3.2x speedup (int64_t) and 10.5x (float) with uniform input. **[Follow the chat link at the main question for more data](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5056/discussion-between-sehe-and-jakub-m)**. Editing things for cleanup and writing explanation will take a bit of time (I'm having the kids)

Answer (score 4):

If values of `max` and `in[]` are far away from 64-bit min/max (say, they are always between -2<sup>61</sup> and +2<sup>61</sup>), you may try a loop without the conditional branch, which may be causing some perf degradation:

```
for(uint32_t i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    max &= -max >> 63; // assuming >> would do arithmetic shift with sign extension
    max += in[i];
    out[i] = max;
}
```

In theory the compiler may do a similar trick as well, but without seeing the disassembly, it's hard to tell if it does it.

Comment: Interesting! It seems to work for tested (simple) cases. aren't the limits actually +- 2^60 , instead of 61? And it gave boost comparable to unfolding the loop. someones -1 is _not_ deserved

Comment: Why 60? That's 3 orders to min/max, which is 63. Overflows become possible when numbers get to half min/max, hence 62. And then I take off one more to be on a safe side, so 61. What if you have both, unrolling and this?

Comment: my mistake with that 63 : ) I tried the times, strange that your hack and loop unfolding they work separately well, and used at once they do not accumulate the gain. I added some results to the main topic

Comment: Alex, can you please explain how this has the same effect as the conditional branch? Because I don't get it :)

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde: The original loop is equivalent to `if (max<0) max=0; max+=in[i]; out[i]=max;`. If a signed integer is less than 0, then the result of shifting it right by its width-1 positions will (on most platforms) have all bits set to 1. Otherwise it'll have all bits set to 0. This gives us `if (max<0) mask=0xFF...FF; else mask=0;` and after this we can do `max &= ~mask;` to achieve the same result as in `if (max<0) max = 0`. I compensate `~` by inverting the condition, inserting `-` before `max` in `if`.

Comment: @Alex: thanks for the explanation, I understand how it works now. Very clever rewrite of the original code. You should definitely not be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

The code appears already pretty fast. Depending on the nature of the in array, you could try special casing, for instance if you happen to know that in a particular invokation all the input numbers are positive, out[i] will be equal to the cumulative sum, with no need for an if branch.

Comment: fast is a very relative notion. You probably mean, it cannot be improved much. I have published some benchmarks, and it is quite depressing to see that the algorithm takes ~5000ms to complete, while using boost::hash_range to create a checksum _over the same data_ takes roughly 3ms :)

Comment: sehe you are right that fast without qualification is not very meaningful. What I meant is "the code is correct and doesn't exhibit obvious inefficiencies". The various good answers (yours included obviously) show that improving on it probably is going to require a more or less drastic rewrite, taking advantage of sophisticated analysis and possibly becoming less portable. It will also probably become less understandable. My suggestion has the only value of being very simple but is clearly not good enough and if the OP really needs to optimize he will have to go the full way.

Answer (score 1):

ensuring the method **isn't virtual**, **inline**, **_*attribute*_((always_inline))** and **-funroll-loops** seem like good options to explore.

Only by you benchmarking them can we determine if they were worthwhile optimizations in your bigger program.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that comes to mind that *might* help a small bit is to use pointers rather than array indices within your loop, something like

```
void theloop(int64_t in[], int64_t out[], size_t N)
{
    int64_t max = in[0];
    out[0] = max;
    int64_t *ip = in + 1,*op = out+1;

    for(uint32_t i = 1; i < N; i++) {
        int64_t v = *ip; 
        ip++;
        max += v;
        if (v > max) max = v;
        *op = max;
        op++
    }
}
```

The thinking here is that an index into an array is liable to compile as taking the base address of the array, multiplying the size of element by the index, and adding the result to get the element address.  Keeping running pointers avoids this.  I'm guessing a good optimizing compiler will do this already, so you'd need to study the current assembler output.

Comment: @Autopopulated, hence the comment to look at the compiler output.  IME, expecting the optimizer will do something for you and acting on that expectation often does not lead to the expected results.

Comment: [Neil Butterworth](http://stackoverflow.com/users/711998/nbt) has recently written a [blog](http://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/the-joy-of-benchmarks/) on benchmarking using just that optimization as example.

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, entertaining article

Answer (score -3):

```
int64_t max = 0, i;

for(i=N-1; i > 0; --i) /* Comparing with 0 is faster */  
{  
    max = in[i] > 0 ? max+in[i] : in[i];
    out[i] = max;

    --i;  /* Will reduce checking of i>=0 by N/2 times */  

    max = in[i] > 0 ? max+in[i] : in[i]; /* Reduce operations v=in[i], max+=v by N times */  
    out[i] = max;         
}

if(0 == i) /* When N is odd */
{ 
    max = in[i] > 0 ? max+in[i] : in[i]; 
    out[i] = max;
}
```

Comment: altering the behaviour/outcome is likely not acceptable for the OP :)

Comment: there is no alteration of the outcome in this logic

Comment: So now, -1: [out of 100 randomized tests](http://pastebin.com/WnQnFwpm) on arrays of length 8 containing values from [-3,+3], only 3 came out _accidentally right_

Comment: Performance: it is using 1.5% _more time_ to produce profoundly _wrong_ output. (full disclosure: [code](http://pastebin.com/yqYJjr8C) and [data](http://pastebin.com/LvYBqUJT))